# React native bottom tab navigation not working and icons appear on top of eachother

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm having a very weird behavior from react navigation,
Whenever I want to use bottom tabs navigation it doesn't load any screen and icons render on top of each other.

I installed all needed packages for navigation to work like
`react-native-safe-area-context`
`react-native-screens`

[image: @react-navigation/bottom-tabs]

Navigation.js

```
import {
  Cases,
  Employees,
  ...
} from './../screens'

export const adminBottomTabs = [
  {
    name: 'CASES',
    label: 'Cases',
    component: Cases,
    icon: 'home',
    icon_active: 'home',
  },
  {
    name: 'EMPLOYEES',
    label: 'Employees',
    component: Employees,
    icon: 'users',
    icon_active: 'users',
  },
  ...
]
```

Admin.jsx (where I load the navigation)

```
export const Admin = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[mainStyles.screen, { flex: 1 }]}>

      <Tab.Navigator>
        {
          adminBottomTabs.map(route => (
            <Tab.Screen
              key={route.name}
              name={route.name}
              component={route.component}
              initialParams={{ name: route.name }}
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarLabel: route.label,
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
                  <Icon name={route.icon} color={color} />
                ),
                tabBarOptions: {
                  activeTintColor: '#333333',
                  inactiveTintColor: '#333333',
                },
              }}

            />
          ))
        }
      </Tab.Navigator>

    </View>
  )
}
```

CustomIcon Component

```
import {createIconSetFromIcoMoon} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import icoMoonConfig from './selection.json';
export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(icoMoonConfig);
```

Comment: Is the Icon component a custom component? If so can you post the code?

Comment: may be you give alignItem:canter to mainStyles.screen.

Comment: @Abe I just updated the question with the custom icon component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grate thanks to @ronakdholariya for his answer, The problem was that I used
`alignItems: 'center'`

My recommendation for further problems like this is to take out everything that can effect the behavior like styles, plugins and bring them back one by one.